# ajax() in Laravel 7

Tags: ajax, laravel-7

My AJAX code is like below

```
       $('select[id="state"]').on('change', function() {
            var stateID =  $(this).val();
            if(stateID) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/cities',
                    type: "GET",
                    data: { id: 7},
                    success:function(data) {
                        $('select[name="city"]').empty();
                        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                            $('select[name="city"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
                        });
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error){
                        var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
                        alert('Error - ' + errorMessage);
                    }
                });
            }else{
                $('select[name="city"]').empty();
            }
        });
```

My route is like below

```
Route::get('/cities/{id}', 'LocationController@getSelectedCityajax');
```

My controller code is like below

```
public function getSelectedCityajax($id)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'success'=>'get your data'
        ]);
    }
```

But I am getting result like below

`Error - 400: Bad Request`

Comment: If your route is `/cities/{id}` and the id is 7 then you have to call URL `/cities/7` and not `/cities?id=7`. Change the Ajax call to `url: '/cities/7'` and remove the `data: { id: 7},` line.

Comment: pass csrf token with ajax it will work.

Comment: Thanks @GuyIncognito. I tried your ways and other ways but I am still getting `Error - 400: Bad Request`. What will be the solution ?

Comment: Thanks @HassanALi. I tried with csrf token  but I am still getting `Error - 400: Bad Request`. Thanks.

Comment: You need to read the server logs to see what the error is.

Comment: Thanks @GuyIncognito. There is no Server Errors in Log.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/PED5q.png

Comment: What happens if you call http://your-domain.com/cities/7 directly in the browser? Do you also get a 400 - Bad Request ?  (Assuming you still use the get route and did not switch to post)

Answer (score 1):

If your route is -`Route::get('/cities/{id}', 'LocationController@getSelectedCityajax');` 
then ajax call should be-

```
$.ajaxSetup({
headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
},
})
$('select[id="state"]').on('change', function() {
        var stateID =  $(this).val();
        if(stateID) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/cities/7',
                type: "GET",
                success:function(data) {
                    $('select[name="city"]').empty();
                    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                        $('select[name="city"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
                    });
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error){
                    var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
                    alert('Error - ' + errorMessage);
                }
            });
        }else{
            $('select[name="city"]').empty();
        }
    });
```

and if u want send data by post request then route should be -

```
Route::post('/cities', 'LocationController@getSelectedCityajax');
```

AJAX Request would be -

```
$.ajaxSetup({
headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
},
})
$.ajax({
                url: '/cities',
                type: "post",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { id: 7},
                success:function(data) {
                    $('select[name="city"]').empty();
                    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                        $('select[name="city"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
                    });
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error){
                    var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText
                    alert('Error - ' + errorMessage);
                }
            });
```

And controller code -

```
public function getSelectedCityajax(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->get('id');
    return response()->json([
        'success'=>'get your data'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @SJR. I tried both of your ways but I am still getting `Error - 400: Bad Request`. What will be the solution ? Thanks.

Comment: are u sending data with get request? because i have updated my answer for post request